# How to get instagram followers list with Java?

Tags: java, jackson, gson, retrofit

i want to parse `Json` with this format:

```
{"data": {
  "user": {
    "edge_follow": {
        "count": 2554, "page_info": {
        "node": {
            "id": "5719761315", "username": "disneyangell" ...
        "node": {
            "id": "2260368333", "username": "moosa_sedaghat",...
        "node": {
            "id": "3982701506", "username": "alidadashi512", ...
        .
        .
        .
```

from this [link](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17874545323001329&id=5797128132&first=1000) ;
i got my `pojo`s from www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
i tried `GsonConverter` and Jackson `ObjectMapper` also

the problem is parsed object's node list is empty or it's zero always.
how to solve this?
if i need to use `CustomConverter` write that for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get the JSON you want you have to be logged in to instagiam. Otherwise you will get an empty "edges" object in the JSON returned from your get request. If you are logged in here is an example to do it with Gson:

The POJO (maybe you need to add getter methods for fields you are interested in):

```
public class FollowJson{
    Data data;
    String status;

    public ArrayList<FollowNode> getFollowNodes(){
        return data.getFollowNodes();
    }

    class Data{
        User user;

        public ArrayList<FollowNode> getFollowNodes(){
            return user.getFollowNodes();
        }
    }

    class User{
        EdgeFollow edge_follow;

        public ArrayList<FollowNode> getFollowNodes(){
            return edge_follow.getFollowNodes();
        }

    }

    class EdgeFollow{
        Integer count;
        ArrayList<OuterNode> edges;
        HashMap<String, Object> page_info;

        public ArrayList<FollowNode> getFollowNodes(){
            ArrayList<FollowNode> bufList = new ArrayList<FollowNode>();
            for(OuterNode outer : edges){
                bufList.add(outer.getNode());
            }
            return bufList;
        }

    }

    class OuterNode{
        FollowNode node;

        public FollowNode getNode(){
            return node;
        }

    }

    class FollowNode {
        Boolean followed_by_viewer;
        String full_name;
        String id;
        Boolean is_verified;
        String profile_pic_url;
        Boolean requested_by_viewer;
        String username;

        public Boolean getFollowedStatus(){
            return followed_by_user;
        }

        public String getId(){
            return id;
        }

        public String getUsername(){
            return username;
        }
    }

}
```

Then pass the POJO.class and the JSON string to the Method:

```
public <T> T getJsonFromString(String jsonString, Class<T> var){
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    return builder.create().fromJson(jsonString, var);
}
```

You can then call getFollowNodes() on the returned object, which returns an array of objects (FollowNode) representing the "nodes" in the JSON.

Comment: thanks i didn't check response body. but now how to get that json with okhttp? i mean how to set cookies or ...

Comment: I never worked with okhttp but in general you could use java.net.CookieManager to handle the cookies. You get the cookies from the respond header, for example by sending a get request to  https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/. You then send a post request to above link with the cookies, parameters (user name and password) and the necessary request header. You can use the developer tools of your browser to check what the post header contains (like : "Host", "csrftoken", ...).

Comment: i found the cookie in the browser Http header and it's working ... thanks again :)